# Using COM Component in VBScript

Tags: c#, javascript, vbscript, com, activex

I searched and did not see the answer on stackoverflow (but maybe missed it).

Wondering, what is the VBScript code needed to set up and call a in a COM Component? The class id is "clsid:0D53A3E8-E51A-49C7-944E-E72A2064F93B"
 and the function signature is

```
bool Read(string filename, ref int[] pix, ref int width, ref int height, bool readOnlyHeader);
```

which is part of:

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("EAA4976A-45C3-4BC5-BC0B-E474F4C3C83B")]
    public interface IComFitsReaderInterface
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        bool Read(string filename, ref int[] pix, ref int width, ref int height, bool readOnlyHeader);

    }

    [Guid("7BD20046-DF8C-44A6-8F6B-687FAA26FA7B"),
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IComFitsReaderEventsInterface
    {
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("0D53A3E8-E51A-49C7-944E-E72A2064F93B"),
        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
        ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IComFitsReaderEventsInterface))]
    public class FitsReader : FitsFile, IComFitsReaderInterface
    {
        public bool Read(string filename, ref int[] pix, ref int width, ref int height, bool readOnlyHeader);
```

...

Note: It looks like I cannot use JavaScript since (as I read) it does not support reference parameters in the COM Component functions. I did use it though to call a function with a single non-reference parameter which worked fine.

Thanks!

Buck

Comment: `1` not a COM signature actually, `2` with COM you have *classes* implementing *interfaces* which in turn have *methods*, so you have one piece missing on your question.

Comment: original post was edited to add some information on the interfaces. Thanks for your feedback.